# Google Site Data to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: database, google-sheets, google-sites

Wondering how to collect data from a Google-site and send that data to a Google Spreadsheet in a form submission.

Any help would be grateful

Cheers

Comment: What kind of data do you wish to gather? Please be a bit more specific.  You can insert a Google Form into your Google Site, but if you want data (like metadata) from a Google Sites it is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

The easier, built-in way, would be to use a Google Form linked to a Google Spreadsheet ( https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809 ) and then embed it on your website ( https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569 )

A more complicated way would be to use the Google Spreadsheet API from Google Site to fill the data, but I don't think you can do that safely.